# How to set flex-basis on secondary axis

Tags: css, flexbox

*How to make a flex item to shrink in secondary axis?*

For example, I have container which has lots of items inside. They all are positioned in column, but I want they width also can be shrinked:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  .item {
    width: 200px;
    flex: 0 1 @item-height;
    //flex-shrink here means Y-axis. How to set flex-shrink for X-axis??
  }
}
```

Comment: Based on what? Content? Viewport size? Number of siblings? Or, like the main axis, available space? If it's the last option, there is no such function in flexbox.

Comment: @Michael_B by available space, unfortunatelly

Comment: The `flex` shorthand, and component long-hand, properties apply only to the main axis. For cross-axis sizing use standard CSS properties.

Answer (score 9):

[image: Flexbox Terms]

The **cross space** or **cross size** is calculated according to the [layout algorithm](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#layout-algorithm):

> **Determine the available main and cross space for the flex items**. For
> each dimension, if that dimension of the flex container’s content box
> is a definite size, use that; if that dimension of the flex container
> is being sized under a min or max-content constraint, the available
> space in that dimension is that constraint; otherwise, subtract the
> flex container’s margin, border, and padding from the space available
> to the flex container in that dimension and use that value. *This might
> result in an infinite value.*

https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#layout-algorithm

The cross-axis is affected by `align-items` and can be affected by `width`, `max-width`, `height`, `max-height`, etc: [Cross-axis MDN notes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Cross_Axis)

So for the equivalent of flex-shrink on the cross axis, you could try using `align-items` and for the equivalent of `flex-basis` you can use percentage `max-width`/`max-height`.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `width: 100%; max-width: 200px;` on `.item`. This should cause your items to shrink to the width of the parent element when it's below 200px. Otherwise the items stay at 200px width.

Works at least as long as you don't use flex-wrap.

Comment: @Johanns the problem is that I need initial width = max-width and equal `200px`. I can't know how much 200px is in percentage. Also I wan't it to shrink if needed

Comment: If the container is more than 200px wide, the "initial width" resulting from these settings *will always be* 200px (the max-width). It will only shrink when the container is less than 200px wide (to the width of the container - 100%). Try it...

Comment: the problem is that container has insuffient content to stretch itself to initial width. I mean the first time you open it has like 150px. But If I set width to 200px - it won't be shrinked